# how to use gdal_rasterize? how to know which attribute to burn with ogrinfo?

Tags: raster, gdal

I have a vector layer I need to rasterize. I guess this is a basic operation, but I haven't found the information I need yet.

First, I have reprojected the vector shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs "+init=EPSG:3763" -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=29 +north +west +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" CLC06_PT_WGS84.shp CLC06_PT.shp
```

The ogrinfo command on the new shapefile yields the following:

> INFO: Open of `CLC06_PT_WGS84.shp'
>        using driver`ESRI Shapefile' successful.
>
> Layer name: CLC06_PT_WGS84
>   Geometry: Polygon
>   Feature Count: 46915
>   Extent: (248668.309849, 3768747.607570) - (537329.149160, 4365413.617030)
>   Layer SRS WKT:
>   PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_29N",
>      GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
>          DATUM["WGS_1984",
>              SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
>          PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
>          UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
>      PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
>      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
>      PARAMETER["central_meridian",-9],
>      PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
>      PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
>      PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
>      UNIT["Meter",1]]
>   FID: Real (11.0)

now, I want to convert it to raster using gdal_rasterize.
The original file contains information on land use (classed as attribute data), and I want that information to be rasterized.

I have tried the -3d option, but I was asked for the feature source, which is not the .dbf nor the .shx files created.

Another try was

```
gdal_rasterize -a FID -sql "select FID, * from CLC06_PT_WGS84" CLC06_PT_WGS84.shp CLC06_PT_WGS84.tif
```

but I got the error message

> ERROR 4: `CLC06_PT_WGS84.tif' does not exist in the file system

I am using gdal 1.6

How can I achieve this?
many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run the process in QGIS and to copy-paste the gdal_rasterize code at to bottom of the rasterize-tool? Just to see if code and error message are the same ...

Comment: thanks for your answer and help.
I haven't, but I would prefer to keep the whole thing under CLI and GDAL for automation purposes.

Comment: i guess, when you copy-paste the code from QGIS you should still be able to automate the process as you wish; it would (maybe) just be an option to check code and syntax as it is the same gdal-tool

Comment: I am not at all at ease with QGIS. Doing some fiddling, I managed to arrive to a raster: setting the -tr or -ts option with gdal_rasterize. In my case, since I want information every 50 metres, I set -tr 50 50.

Comment: well, it seems I do not get what I want (3 numbers classifiers) in the ASCII file. I guess that has to do with the -a FID -sql "select FID, * from CLC06_PT_WGS84" options for the gdal_rasterize command. Any help How I can understand which field to burn on the raster?

Comment: SOLVED. The ogrinfo with the right flags (-al -so) yielded information on the fields, so that I was able to identify the 'CODE_06' field as the one containing the information on land use. The command to produce the tiff is then `gdal_rasterize -tr 50 50 -a CODE_06 -l CLC06_PT_WGS84 CLC06_PT_WGS84.shp CLC06_PT_WGS84.tiff`